# delete * from table not working in python,pymysql

Tags: python-3.x, pymysql

This code does not produce any error but does not delete records when using pymysql in python

```
import pymysql

db = pymysql.connect("localhost","root","root","mydb" )

cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "delete * from student"
try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()      
except:
    db.rollback()
db.close()
```

I'm aware of the truncate workaround but why would this not produce the desired result

Comment: can you try changing query that your are executing to below query 

sql = "delete  from student"

Comment: Probably you are getting a `SyntaxError` from MySQL that is suppressed in your error path, which simply rolls back the (empty) transaction. Add a `raise` after the `db.rollback()` to make the error visible.

Comment: @PythonUser - delete from student works. What's the issue with '*'.

Comment: @user2722968- can you be more specific . How should I use raise with syntax as I am new to this.